# When Firefox loads, is code for "Ask to Active" Plugins loaded?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, plugins, browser-plugin

When Firefox loads, does it load Plugins that are set to "Ask to Activate"?  Or is the code for any such Plugin only loaded once it is manually activated?

Note the question is specifically asking about Plugins, and not Extensions (which have no such option).